# Project does not run on other system without visual studio

Tags: c#, linq, sqlite, visual-studio-2012, devart

I have created a project which is using devart Linq SQL and .Net 4.5. The steps I followed are,

- Built the project.
- Copied the Debug/Release folder to another system.
- Installed devart + dotnet4.5 in this system.
- Tried to run the .exe.

But nothing happens, no error no appearance of any thing.
If I have VS installed in that other system then this runs smoothly.
I'm not able to identify the problem.

Comment: What does the exe do? if you run it on the system it was built, what happens?

Comment: It runs perfectly in the system in which it is built and also in any other which has Visual Studio Installed.

Comment: Make the program output some logging to a text file somewhere, then run the program and see if a text file is created with output from your program, that way you'll have a better idea if the exe you are running is actually running your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem after a long time of research. I was using DB in the constructor of first form and My database file path in 'App.config' and Devart Linq's '****.lqml' was not absolute path and hard coded, this was the cause of the 'Application not working properly' in other systems. Just made it absolute and it is working fine now. Thanks All :)

Comment: Glad.. It worked.. But just a hardcoded path problem made you worried this much?? Why couldn't you diagnose it easily??

Comment: @Sayka Because i had already made the path like ".\mydb.db" once. After some other type of errors from db i recreated LINQ connection that made this path HARDCODED again. I forgot this and was searching for other types pf errors! :)

Answer (score 1):

Publish the project by right clicking project package on the solution explorer and publish..
Go to the published folder and search for the file named .deploy. Rename it to .exe and try

Answer (score 1):

To deploy applications written with the help of [LinqConnect](http://www.devart.com/linqconnect/) you don't need to install the copy of LinqConnect product on your  deployment machines. You should register run-time assemblies Devart.Data.SQLite.dll, Devart.Data.dll, Devart.Data.SQLite.Linq.dll  and Devart.Data.Linq.dll at Global Assembly Cache (GAC) or place them in the bin folder of your application. When deploying ASP.NET  applications it is also necessary to have Devart.Data.Linq.Web.dll and App_Licenses.dll assemblies available.

JIC: these assemblies can be found in the folder where LinqConnect is installed.

For example, open your application in Visual Studio, set the Copy Local property to True for each Devart assembly in the Solution  Explorer and build your application. After that, all necessary Devart assemblies will appear in the bin folder of your application  (in your case - bin\Release). Make sure you have these files available there:

- Devart.Data.dll;
- Devart.Data.Linq.dll;
- Devart.Data.SQLite.dll;
- Devart.Data.SQLite.Linq.dll.

After that copy the Debug/Release folder to another system and try running the project again.

Comment: that was help full but that wasnt my problem! :)